# rounding integers of multiple of 50

Tags: php, rounding

will be use 50 only if have 99 points.
use full 100 - if have 100 points.
use 150 only - if have 151 points.

i.e: allow 50, 100 ,150, 200, 250 depends on points.

Comment: The arithmetic is basically:  floor((val + 25) / 50) * 50.  I'm not sure how to express this in php.  (Note: the expression is slightly more complicated if you want 25 to round one way and 75 another.)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 1):

I'd divide the number by 50, [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) it, and multiply back by 50. E.g.:

```
$num = 99;
$rounded = 50 * floor($num / 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete in all corner , still i am providing you codes which will solve your problem -

```
<?php
function getResult($point)
{
$i=$point/50;
if($i==0)
return 50;
else
return 50*$i;
}
?>
```

Now use that function wherever required..